# How to read from user 2 values in python and find the highest GPA?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, int, gpa

How do I write a python code to read from user the Student Name and GPA in one line, but if user enter a word like (off) the program stops .. I want to use while loop and Calculate and print the highest GPA and student name?

2 values = First int .. Second String.
like = GPA ... name

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far and the error(s) you are getting. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you want to do with the results or how you want to store them but this should get you started with what you need.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_mean_grades():
    students = defaultdict(list)
    while True:
        data = input('Enter your GPA followed by your name: ')
        if data.upper() == 'STOP':
            break
        else:
            gpa, name = data.split(' ', 1)
            students[name].append(float(gpa))
    print()
    for student, grades in students.items():
        average = sum(grades) / len(grades)
        print(f"{student} has an average grade of {average}")

Enter your GPA followed by your name: 4.3 Tom Morris
Enter your GPA followed by your name: 2.2 Fred York
Enter your GPA followed by your name: 4.8 Tom Morris
Enter your GPA followed by your name: 3.3 Fred York
Enter your GPA followed by your name: STOP

Tom Morris has an average grade of 4.55
Fred York has an average grade of 2.75
```

Answer (score -2):

```
data = []
while True:
    inp = [i for i in input("Please enter your name followed by your GPA: ").strip().split()]
    if (len(inp)==1 or inp[0] == 'off'): break
    data.append({'Name':(' '.join([str(i) for i in inp[:-1]])) , 'GPA':float(inp[-1])})

# print(data)
```

```
Please enter your name followed by your GPA: Kuldeep Singh 2.1
Please enter your name followed by your GPA: Kuldeep 3.1
Please enter your name followed by your GPA: Peter Smith 4.0
Please enter your name followed by your GPA: off
[{'GPA': 2.1, 'Name': 'Kuldeep Singh'},
 {'GPA': 3.1, 'Name': 'Kuldeep'},
 {'GPA': 4.0, 'Name': 'Peter Smith'}]
```

[image]

Comment: I can not use split ??

Comment: Yes, why not?  :)

Comment: name , grade ("Enter Your Name And Your Grade :") . split(" , ")

while grade != "stop": 
    if grade >= 90 and grade <=100:
        print("A")
    elif grade >= 80 and grade<= 89:
        print("B")
    elif grade >= 70 and grade <= 79:
        print("C")
    elif grade >= 0 and grade <=60:
        print("Fail")

Comment: this is the question .. Write a program that reads from the user several lines of input. Each line includes a student's name and his/her GPA (as a real number).  
The program should calculate and print the highest GPA (rounded to 2 decimal places) and name of the student who has achieved it.